# When is it safe to say that improvements on a model are superfluous (even if one had e.g. "only" 80% accuracy)?

Tags: accuracy

When is it safe to say that improvements on a model are superfluous (even if one had e.g. "only" 80% accuracy)?

If the 80% accurate model is used for e.g. medical diagnosis or drug discovery, then I'd ask, whether getting 20% wrong can still lead to catastrophes.

Answer (score 3):

As you hinted, the consequences of the improvements of a model's results are entirely different for different domains and different scales.

For instance, the consequences of a false negative diagnosis can be severe, therefore the reduction of the false positive rate of a diagnostic model can greatly improve its applicability.

Likewise, in a business of huge scale, any tiny improvement in the product recommender system can mean a lot of money in revenue.

In conclusion: **it depends**.

Comment: The more interesting question would be though, if one gets, say, an 80% accuracy model, then it would be beneficial to know whether seeking a better model is worth the investment, since it might also take quite a long time. With p-values people could argue that when a certain threshold is reached, then it's sufficient.

Comment: I disagree. My opinion is that you should not measure the "value" of a model from its accuracy, but from whatever business value the model provides. If an improvement of 0.1 in accuracy translates into \$\$\$\$ (much greater than the investment to achieve the improvement), would you just accept that the p-value says that there is no statistical evidence to reject the null hypothesis and therefore having an accuracy of 80.1 cannot be considered different from 80.0?

Comment: If the businesses ethics require that things are as accurate as possible, yet there might still be a resource limitation of some sort. It could be wrong to do with a worse model, even if it made $$$.

Comment: Sure, there can be a lot of different factors at play, and that's why my answer was "it depends".

Comment: Noe, I like the comments. I recall a paper, but cannot find it now, about improving the model where it matters. Take AUROC as a metric. There might be an improvement in AUROC across models. But where is the improvement? If the business cutoff value is 0.1 (or multiple 0.05, 0.1, 0.2), but the rank-order improvement is greater than 0.5, there is no improvement in the business results. A swap analysis may show slightly worse performance where it matters but outweighed by the better performance where it does not matter.